# Hide div based on if some elements will be inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

I have a situation. Sharepoint translates server side Linkfields to regular HTML  tag during page rendering as follows: The first one is when some one enters value for Website field. Second one, content editor left it empty, so page rendered without anchor tag. Depending on whether RegisterLink contains an anchor tag or not, I should hide RegisterOrangeBtnHolder, if not  tag.
This didn't work: please help!

```
    if ($($('.RegisterLink').length) <0){
       $('.RegisterOrangeButton').hide();     
    }

<div class="RegisterBtnHolder"> 
    <span class="RegisterOrangeButton">
        <span class="RegisterLink">
            <a href="http://www.google.com">Register Online</a>
        </span>                             
    </span>
</div>


<div class="RegisterBtnHolder"> 
    <span class="RegisterOrangeButton">
        <span class="RegisterLink">

        </span>                             
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Will there be more than one of these on the page and you want to only hide those which do not have a link?

Comment: No it will be just one register button, which needs to show or hide based on if there is an anchor tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.RegisterOrangeBtnHolder').not(':has(a)' ).hide()
```

jQuery has a wealth of selectors to simplify many filters

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/